# (macOS Big Sur) CMake Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES)

Tags: cmake, macos-big-sur, openblas

I'm trying to make [MultiNest/pymultinest](http://johannesbuchner.github.io/pymultinest-tutorial/install.html) on macOS; this program requires openblas and lapack as dependencies. I've installed both using homebrew, but when I try to cmake in the MultiNest build directory, I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.20.5/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.20.5/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.20.5/share/cmake/Modules/FindBLAS.cmake:1045 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.20.5/share/cmake/Modules/FindLAPACK.cmake:265 (find_package)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.20.5/share/cmake/Modules/FindLAPACK.cmake:291 (_lapack_find_dependency)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:31 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

I already have a number of paths declared;

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib/pkgconfig"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/lapack/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/lapack/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/lapack/lib/pkgconfig"

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openblas:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export BLAS=/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib/libopenblas.a
```

Why can't cmake find BLAS on macOS? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `/usr/local/opt/lapack` and `/usr/local/opt/openblas` to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, like so:

```
$ cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/usr/local/opt/lapack;/usr/local/opt/openblas"
```

Homebrew doesn't symlink them to `/usr/local` to avoid conflicts with Apple's own Accelerate.framework BLAS implementation. Such packages are called "keg-only" in Homebrew's parlance.

You should also unset *all* of the environment variables you set because CMake is responsible for setting up include and library paths.

Documentation links of interest:

- **CMake search procedure:** https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure
- **Environment variables CMake respects:** https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-env-variables.7.html
- **FindBLAS module**: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBLAS.html
- **FindLAPACK module**: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindLAPACK.html

Comment: You might need to fiddle with the `BLA_VENDOR` variable, too: one of `OpenBLAS` or `Generic` ought to work if the default (empty) doesn't.

Comment: I've cleared my exported environment variables that I set for lapack/blas and tried adding the flags above for cmake, but it resulted in the same exact error. How can I change the BLA_VENDOR variable? Is that a flag that I have to pass into cmake?